# Qix diagonally adjacent movement

Tags: game-design, algorithm

I'm implementing a Qix clone game and I do not have any problems with implementation but rather with possible scenario.

Is this a valid scenario for this game and if yes how exactly should gameplay go in this case?

Black - Filled, Red - Current Player's Path, Blue - Player

[image: Step 1]

If this is a possible scenario, then after completing the path player will end up with two diagonally adjacent rectangles.

[image: Step 2]

After that player can start moving from the bottom of the top rectangle to the right.

[image: Step 3]

In this case it should be immediately considered as a complete path and fill 1x1 square or player can create a path adjacent to the top of the bottom rectangle?

[image: Step 4]

Comment: Just because the developers of the game you want to clone made a certain design decision does not mean it's the only possible design decision or even a good one. What do *you* think would make for a more interesting game?

Comment: As a non-Qix player, it's not clear to me what the consequences of this decision are, or by what criteria we should evaluate them to decide which outcome is "correct" for your game. Can you edit your question to elaborate on this?

Comment: Asking "how game X does thing Y" is not [on-topic for GDSE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). While that's usually applied to implementation, asking "does game X allow scenario Y" doesn't strike me as on-topic either. In order to be on-topic, this question needs to focus on how the situation described is a problem for your game.